# How can i extract(.find()) div(or span) that don't have class

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the web page id from html of this{https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=python&sort%20=i} site.

my code is this...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = f"https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=python&sort%20=i"

def extract_job(html):
    title = html.find("h2", {"class": "mb4 fc-black-800 fs-body3"}).find('a')["title"]
    company_row = html.find("h3", {"class": "fc-black-700 fs-body1 mb4"}).find_all("span", recursuve = False)
    try:
        company = company_row[0].get_text(strip=True)
    except:
        company = "None"
    try:
        location = company_row[1].get_text(strip=True).strip("\n")
    except:
        location = "None"
    return {'title': title, 'company': company, 'location': location}

def extract_jobs(last_page):
    
    jobs = []
    for page in range(last_page):
        print(f"Scrpping so: Page: {page}")
        result = requests.get(f"{URL}&pg={page+1}")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
        results = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "grid--cell fl1"})
        for result in results:
            job = extract_job(result)
            jobs.append(job)
    return jobs

print(extract_jobs(1))
```

but my code give me only [](empty list).

why...?

and how can i get data-jobid from this html?

i'm trying to extract <data_jobid> from below Html

```
<div data-jobid="185876" data-result-id="185876" data-preview-url="/jobs/185876?a=10kTLndTtq3S&amp;so=i&amp;sec=False&amp;pg=1&amp;offset=0&amp;total=163&amp;srp=True&amp;so_medium=Internal&amp;so_source=JobSearchPreview" data-beacon-url="/jobs/n/v/185876?url=%2Fjobs%2F185876%3Fa%3D10kTLndTtq3S%26so%3Di%26sec%3DFalse%26pg%3D1%26offset%3D0%26total%3D163%26srp%3DTrue%26so_medium%3DInternal%26so_source%3DJobSearchPreview&amp;referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fcareers.stackoverflow.com%2Fso-proxy%2Fjobs%3Fq%3Dpython%26sort%20%2B%3Di" class="-job js-result js-dismiss-overlay-container ps-relative _selected js-selected p12 pl24 _featured">
        <div class="dismiss-overlay ps-absolute ta-center t0 r0 b0 l0 grid ai-center jc-center o90 bg-black-050 z-active">
            <p class="mb0">Okay, you won’t see this job anymore. <a href="#" class="js-undismiss-job" data-id="185876">Undo</a></p>
        </div>
    
    <div class="grid">
                <div class="grid--cell fl-shrink mr12 w48 h48">
                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI3Jl.png?s=48" class="w48 h48 bar-sm">
                </div>
        <div class="grid--cell fl1 ">
                <span class="float-right ml12 mrn12 bg-yellow-200 fc-yellow-900 px8 py4 tt-uppercase fw-bold fs-fine bar-sm">featured</span>

            <h2 class="mb4 fc-black-800 fs-body3">
<a href="/jobs/185876/senior-software-engineer-frontend-deepfield-networks?a=10kTLndJTsqc&amp;so=i&amp;pg=1&amp;offset=0&amp;total=163&amp;so_medium=Internal&amp;so_source=JobSearch&amp;q=python" title="Senior Software Engineer (Frontend)" class="s-link stretched-link">Senior Software Engineer (Frontend)</a>            </h2>

            <h3 class="fc-black-700 fs-body1 mb4">
                <span>Deepfield Networks
                </span>
                •
                <span class="fc-black-500">
Ann Arbor, MI                </span>
            </h3>
```

moreover i had tried to add this cord

```
id_list = soup.find_all("div", {"data-jobid": True})
```

this gave me the whole cord that include the 'data-jobid'

but i what to attract only numbers like <185876>.(this number is from above HTML cord)

help me...

Comment: I don't see a problem with the first code snippet,  I'm getting the following data returned `Scrpping so: Page: 0
[{'title': 'Principal Software Engineer -Python - Contact Center', 'company': 'Delivery Hero SE'....`

Answer (score 0):

The first code in runs goodly kindly check your internet **bandwidth**

**kind of output what i got:**

```py
Scrpping so: Page: 0
([{'title': 'Principal Software Engineer -Python - Contact Center', 'company': 'Delivery Hero SE', 'location': 'Berlin, Germany'}, {'title': 'Senior Software Engineer - Python', 'company': 'YouGov', 'location': 'Warsaw, Poland'}, {'title': 'Python Developer', 'company': 'YouGov', 'location': 'Bengaluru, India'}, {'title': 'Python Developer', 'company': 'GeekyWorks', 'location': 'Pune, India'}, {'title': 'Python Developers', 'company': 'JB Solutions', 'location': ''}, {'title': 'Full Stack (Python/React) Software engineer', 'company': 'JPMorgan Chase Bank, N.A.', 'location': 'New York, NY'}, {'title': 'Mid-Level Backend Software Engineer (Python / Django)', 'company': 'Tivix, Inc.', 'location': 'Wrocław, Poland'}, {'title': 'Back-End Developer (Python/Django)', 'company': 'Apacio Ltd', 'location': 'Theale, UK'}, {'title': 'Python Software Developer', 'company': 'Old Mission Capital, LLC', 'location': 'Chicago, IL'}, {'title': 'Python Developer/Bangalore', 'company': 'Talent Zone Consultants',
```